# 2.1.3 installation returning 404 on admin

Tags: htaccess, 404, magento-2.1.3

I just finished installing, was given the sucess page, clicked on the link do admin and I get a 404 page.

When I go to the home page, there's a bunch of plain html with no CSS or JS working. It looks like a htaccess problem, but It's first time trying Magento and I have no idea how its htaccess was supposed to look like.

I'm running on `PHP 7`, `Mysql 5.6` and `Ubuntu 16.04`. It's a brand new installation on a brand new server.

So far, I've installed php extensions shown as required on the `magento-check` page and the ones required to run `composer install`

Does anyone know how to solve that?